# Exemplo Login com autenticação basic auth utilizando Alamofire?

Tags: json, rest, autenticação, alamofire, swift-3

Estou tentando fazer uma tela de login onde utilizo Alamofire para fazer a requisição, porém com os exemplos do próprio site Alamofire não está dando certo.

Se alguém puder ajudar com um código de exemplo, agradeceria muito!!

Qual o problema? 
Tento utilizar o basic auth do Alamofire para realizar a autenticação, porém não estou tento sucesso.

Exemplo do código que estou usando e testando:

```
import UIKit
```

import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


@IBOutlet weak var txtEmail: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var txtSenha: UITextField!


@IBAction func bntLogin(_ sender: Any) {



    //let user = txtEmail.text
    //let password = txtSenha.text
    //let credentialData = "\(user):\(password)".data(using: <#T##String.Encoding#>)
    //let base64Credentials = credentialData?.base64EncodedData(options: <#T##Data.Base64EncodingOptions#>)
    //let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"]


    //let user = txtEmail.text
    //let password = txtSenha.text
    /*
    var headers: HTTPHeaders = [:]

    if let authorizationHeader = Request.authorizationHeader(user: user!, password: password!) {
        headers[authorizationHeader.key] = authorizationHeader.value
    }

    Alamofire.request("https://www.url.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/users", headers: headers).responseJSON {

        response in debugPrint(response)

    }
    */

    let username = txtEmail.text
    let password = txtSenha.text

    let loginString = String(format: "%@:%@", username!, password!)
    let loginData = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString()

    //Cria uma requisição
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.url.com.br/wp-json/wp/v2/users")
    var request = URLRequest(url:url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    // executa
    let urlConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self)


}







override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Aparentemente o q vc está fazendo está certo. Basicamente codificando username:password em Base64 e enviando como parte do header http "Authorization". Isso é basic authentication... qual é o erro?

Comment: E como eu verifico, se realmente o usuário conseguiu logar ou deu erro?

Comment: A partir do momento que vc recebe dados da url q chamou e/ou não recebeu nenhum erro 4xx eu assumo que a sua autenticação funcionou. Qual é o status code?

Comment: Qual parte desse monte de códigos, no caso estaria correto, por que tenho alguns comentados ?

Comment: Eu não não olhei o código comentado. Mas eu tbem não programo em swift, mas programo em C++ e consigo entender o q está rolando. Independente do código, se vc não estiver tendo erros de compilação, o processo está correto para basic authentication. O servidor tem q te mandar um código 2xx para sucesso ou 4xx pra erro. Qual código vc está recebendo?

Comment: Quando eu mando a requisição ele apenas me retorna os json

Comment: Então coloque um usuário e senha qqer e faça o teste negativo. Se o servidor retornar código 4xx então está funcionando. Se com a senha errada vc ainda receber a resposta e dados, o servidor esta mal configurado e permitindo qqer request indepenente de credenciais.

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar.

Comment: Vc tem q estar sempre de olho no código HTTP, principalmente quando estiver fazendo autenticação baseada no webserver. Boa sorte.